# VS2015: Live Code Analyzer: How to infer "possible" variable value or a call stack?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I would like to use a Live Code Analyzer to prevent other devs from making mistakes when coding around a specific method.

The method in question returns generic list of enums. This list is immutable (but not declared as so). How do I create a custom Live Code Analyzer that would give a compiler error if somebody tries to add to that list?

Example

```
List<MyEnum> list1 = GetList_Mutable();
List<MyEnum> list2 = GetList_Immutable();
...
list1.Add(another_element)  // This is OK and should be allowed 
list2.Add(another_element)  // Live code analyzer should catch that
```

In other words - can Live Code Analyzer get access to the "possible" call stack or infer where the specific value comes from?

Comment: You can try to use the tutorial from MSDN - 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879356.aspx

Let me know if that works for you if yes I'll post it as answer

Comment: I went through couple existing tutorials, including linked one. I do not see how to get "imaginary" call stack or anything beyond the currently analyzed block of code.

Comment: @DeJaVo I looked over the tutorials, and I did not see how to address this issue. Can you give more detail?